# Rails 3.1: How can I precompile a binary asset that isn't a Javascript, CSS, or Image file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to embed a Unity3D webplayer object using some javascript that is in my `application.html.erb` file...

```
if (typeof unityObject != "undefined")
{
    unityObject.embedUnity("unityPlayer", <%= asset_path('unity/webplayer.unity3d') %> , 960, 640);
}
```

I've added the `webplayer.unity3d` file to my `app/assets/unity/` folder and I added `config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/unity"` to my `application.rb` file to include the new unity folder as an assets folder.  However, when I precompile the assets using  `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on the command line, my webplayer.unity3d file never gets precompiled.  How can I precompile this file?

Thanks so much in advance for all your wisdom!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this file to your precompile array:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['webplayer.unity3d']
```

Edit: Changed to correct syntax!

Comment: do you get a message saying that, or an error on the front end?

Comment: yeah, the server logs give me a "webplayer.unity3d was not precompiled" when the server attempts to serve the file. if it helps, i'm using Heroku as my host.

Comment: i did, it still chokes.  it finds the file just fine, but it can't use it because it's not "precompiled"